# Laravel Sum not calculating properly for 1 column in database

Tags: laravel

Good Evening,
I stuck with some strange situation, where i am not getting sum of column properly and showing 1 less in the sum of one specific column but for other 2 column sum is showing correctly.

Here is the Code

```
$milksalecustomerdata   = customermilksale::selectraw('(SUM(buffalomilk)) as "totalbmilk", (SUM(a2milk)) as "totala2milk", (SUM(jerseymilk)) as "totaljmilk", (SUM(totalmilk)) as "totalmilk"')

    ->whereBetween('saledate',['2023-01-31','2023-01-31'])
    ->get();
```

Here i am getting out put as

```
    "totalbmilk" => "36.50"      here actual total is 37.50 
    "totala2milk" => "26.50"     total is correct
    "totaljmilk" => "15.50"      total is correct
    "totalmilk" => "78.50"       total milk is less than 1.
```

I also checked the same in sqlworkbench my database, there total showing correctly.

Can any one help me on the same

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: share your first column of all values which you want to sum and also able to share Database structure?

Comment: Thank u for reply. My database is huge, till added screenshot, Is that ok?